# How to access continuity through applescript or command line

Tags: applescript, continuity

Goal:
I want to handoff my localhost site to my phone for testing. I can access my localhost by going to `http://my.ip.add.ress/localhost` on my iphone. Of course, on my computer the actual address is just `http://localhost`. Instead of typing that address I want to trigger a script that will "handoff" the concatenation of my computer's ip address + `localhost/page`.

My question is if I can trigger a "handoff" through applescript or command-line. Is there a handoff API?

I'm *not* asking about how to get my computer's ip address.

Comment: After writing this I searched "handoff API" and found these docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Handoff/HandoffFundamentals/HandoffFundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014338-CH3-SW1, way more complicated than I was hoping for.

Comment: What about just using `http://my.ip.add.ress/localhost/page`  or `servername.local/page` instead of `localhost` on your computer? Handoff will work automatically then..

Answer (score 1):

You can probably avoid all the hassle by just using one nice service - http://xip.io

Instead of browsing to http://localhost - look up your IP and browse to http://192.168.12.13.xip.io/

Of course, your actual IP address for the local host is needed unless your router was set up to assign your test Mac 192.168.12.13 - even though you aren't asking how to get your IP, that's the key to making this easy for safari to hand off the session from macOS to iOS.

---

> **Does xip.io cost anything?**
>
> Nope! xip.io is a free service from [Basecamp](https://basecamp.com/), the
>   creators of [Pow](http://pow.cx/). We were tired of jumping through hoops
>   to test our apps on other devices and decided to solve
>   the problem once and for all.